# What is the value of $i^{i^{i^\ldots}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, tetration, power-towers

> What is the value of $i^{i^{i^\ldots}}$?

My effort is the following: If $z, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z \neq 0$ then we can write $z^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha \log z} = e^{\alpha [ \log |z|+i \text{ Arg z} + 2 \pi i m]}$ where $ m=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$  and Arg z is the principle argument of the complex number $z$. But in above expression we don't have the finite no of exponents, so I am not sure how should I use this formula to the solve above problem. Thanks and Regards!

Comment: One doesn't write $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\infty$ for an infinite geometric series, so by the same token on probably shouldn't write $\infty$ in the exponent here.

Comment: By $\infty $ there I mean I am taking exponents infinite times not infinity in the exponents.

Comment: If the expression makes sense, it should be a number $z$ with $i^z=z$, so $z=e^{\frac \pi2iz}$

Comment: Each time you do an exponent you have to pick a branch cut.  Given all the possible branch choices I'd think the answer is the entire unit circle (or at least dense in the unit circle).

Answer (score 5):

Let us denote your power tower by $a$. Then assuming it converges
\begin{gather*}
i^a=a \\
\frac 1i=\left( \frac 1a \right)^{1/a} \\[6pt]
-\ln i =\left( \frac 1 a\right)\ln\left( \frac 1a\right) \\[6pt]
-\ln i=e^{\ln\left( \frac 1a\right)}\ln\left( \frac 1a\right) \\[6pt]
\ln \left( \frac 1a\right) = \mathop{W}(-\ln i) \\[6pt]
\frac 1a=-\frac{\ln i}{\mathop W (-\ln i)} \\[6pt]
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
a &= -\frac{\mathop{W}(-\ln i)}{\ln i} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2i}{\pi}\mathop{W}\left( -\frac 12\pi i\right)\\[6pt]
&\approx 0.44+0.36i
\end{align*}

where $\mathop{W}$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: "assuming it converges" Does it?